# How to use validate-digits-range validation in magento?

Tags: validation, magento-1.7

Hi Friends I want to validate number range in magento. I also got validation class  validate-digits-range. But i don't know to how to pass that minimum and maximum value for that validation. 
If anybody know means kindly share that example. Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's some docs for input validation in Magento 1.x
https://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/
But they still don't tell you how to use validate-digits-range

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use in text form field like :

```
... class="required-entry validate-digits-range digits-range-10-20"...
```

This will validate the value to be between 10 and 20.

Answer (score 1):

See the following example for a range between 1 and 50:
**validate-number-range number-range-1-50**

```
<field id="radius" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
   <label>Delivery radius</label>        
   <validate>validate-number validate-number-range number-range-1-50</validate>
</field>
```